# How do I get the year value of the selected option with the present year in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a combobox of year options with 2 year interval. If the user selects the one with the present year which is 2014-2016 (because 2016 is the present year). I want to get or know that the user's option is the one with the current year. Don't mind about the rest option, but just the one with the present year because I'm gonna use it in another condition. Help please.

```
<select name="year">
    <option>Year:</option>
<?php
    for($i=date('Y'); $i>1999; $i=$i-2) {
    $selected = '';
    $year2 = $i-2;
        if ($year == $i) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
        echo ('<option value="'.$year2. " - " . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2.' - '.$i.'</option>'."\n");

        }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: "get that data". get it how/where? it's a select. doesn't matter what option the user selects - when the form's submitted, that selected option will be submitted with the rest of the form...

Comment: Your question hardly makes any sense. What "data" are you talking about? Also when and where exactly are you planning to get this "data"?? Please be sure to ask a question with a proper explanation about what exactly your objective is.

Comment: I understand that whatever he selects it is what will be submitted. But I want to know how will I know if he selected the one with the current year. @MarcB because if he did, a privilege will be given to him. something like that so I need to know if he chose the option with the current year.

Comment: `if ($_GET['year'] == (date('Y') - 2)) {  user selected "current" year" }`? you don't have to embed the "2014-2016" text as your value. just embed the first year value, since the second one can be trivially calculated. then it's a simple matter of checking the field value against "current year" and seeing if they match.

Comment: You are right. I'll do it that way instead. Sorry, didn't thought of that before. Thank you @MarcB